# Tensorflow: How to use a Ragged Tensor as an index into a normal tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, ragged, ragged-tensors

I have a 2D RaggedTensor consisting of indices I want from each row of a full tensor, e.g.:

```
[
    [0,4],
    [1,2,3],
    [5]
]
```

into

```
[
    [200, 305, 400, 20, 20, 105],
    [200, 315, 401, 20, 20, 167],
    [200, 7, 402, 20, 20, 105],
]
```

gives

```
[
    [200,20],
    [315,401,20],
    [105]
]
```

How can I achieve this in the most efficient way (preferably only with `tf` functions)? I believe that things like `gather_nd` are able to take RaggedTensors but I cannot figure out how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather), with the `batch_dims` keyword argument:

```
>>> tf.gather(tensor,indices,batch_dims=1)
<tf.RaggedTensor [[200, 20], [315, 401, 20], [105]]>
```